# How to disable ignite baseline auto-just?

Tags: ignite, persistent

Ignite 2.8.0, I enable persistent, code like this:

```
        IgniteConfiguration igniteCfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
        //igniteCfg.setClientMode(true);

        DataStorageConfiguration dataStorageCfg = new DataStorageConfiguration();
        dataStorageCfg.getDefaultDataRegionConfiguration().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        igniteCfg.setDataStorageConfiguration(dataStorageCfg);


        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(igniteCfg);
```

Then some exception like below:

```
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Joining persistence node to in-memory cluster couldn't be allowed due to baseline auto-adjust is enabled and timeout equal to 0
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.checkFailedError(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1997)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.joinTopology(ServerImpl.java:1116)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.spiStart(ServerImpl.java:427)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.spiStart(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:2099)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:297)
    ... 15 more
```

Anyony can help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After starting first node, invoke `ignite.cluster().baselineAutoAdjustEnabled(false)`

You can also use `bin/control.(sh|bat) --baseline auto_adjust [disable|enable] [timeout <timeoutMillis>] [--yes]`

Please note that we don't recommend running mixed persistent~non-persistent clusters since they see very few testing. If you must, make sure that data regions have the same persistenceEnabled settings on all nodes.