# use ignite,but the same configuration, cache rebrance can be used in the 2.6 , but rebrance skip is always prompted in the 2.8 version

Tags: ignite

please help me !I Upgrade ignite version from 2.6 to 2.8, but the same configuration, cache rebrance can be used in the 2.6 , but rebrance skip is always prompted in the 2.8 version

this is my configurations:
[image]

these are start logs:

skip reblance in version 2.8：
[sys-#56%ignite-192.168.111.56-8082%] INFO org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor - Finish proxy initialization, cacheName=gatewayNodeAndMqttTopicCache, localNodeId=a59d358f-ba85-4dcd-8a68-844cb720c4f2
[sys-#56%ignite-192.168.111.56-8082%] INFO org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor - Finish proxy initialization, cacheName=ignite-sys-cache, localNodeId=a59d358f-ba85-4dcd-8a68-844cb720c4f2
[sys-#56%ignite-192.168.111.56-8082%] INFO org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor - Finish proxy initialization, cacheName=routeInfoAndComputeCache, localNodeId=a59d358f-ba85-4dcd-8a68-844cb720c4f2
[sys-#56%ignite-192.168.111.56-8082%] INFO org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor - Finish proxy initialization, cacheName=thingInfoCache, localNodeId=a59d358f-ba85-4dcd-8a68-844cb720c4f2
[sys-#56%ignite-192.168.111.56-8082%] INFO org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor - Finish proxy initialization, cacheName=nodeInfoCache, localNodeId=a59d358f-ba85-4dcd-8a68-844cb720c4f2
[sys-#56%ignite-192.168.111.56-8082%] INFO org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor - Finish proxy initialization, cacheName=Compute-192.168.111.65-53400, localNodeId=a59d358f-ba85-4dcd-8a68-844cb720c4f2
[sys-#56%ignite-192.168.111.56-8082%] INFO org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor - Finish proxy initialization, cacheName=Compute-192.168.111.56-8082, localNodeId=a59d358f-ba85-4dcd-8a68-844cb720c4f2
[sys-#56%ignite-192.168.111.56-8082%] INFO org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture - Completed partition exchange [localNode=a59d358f-ba85-4dcd-8a68-844cb720c4f2, exchange=GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2, minorTopVer=0], evt=NODE_JOINED, evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=a59d358f-ba85-4dcd-8a68-844cb720c4f2, consistentId=4f304981-0904-4dbb-adf3-08daf37b0a80, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.111.56], sockAddrs=HashSet [/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500, /192.168.111.56:47500], discPort=47500, order=2, intOrder=2, lastExchangeTime=1594168281653, loc=true, ver=2.8.1#20200521-sha1:86422096, isClient=false], done=true, newCrdFut=null], topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2, minorTopVer=0]]
[sys-#56%ignite-192.168.111.56-8082%] INFO org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture - Exchange timings [startVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2, minorTopVer=0], resVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2, minorTopVer=0], stage="Waiting in exchange queue" (79 ms), stage="Exchange parameters initialization" (6 ms), stage="Baseline change callback" (27 ms), stage="Components activation" (39 ms), stage="Determine exchange type" (370 ms), stage="Preloading notification" (1 ms), stage="WAL history reservation" (3 ms), stage="Restore partition states" (25 ms), stage="After states restored callback" (24 ms), stage="Waiting for Full message" (233 ms), stage="Affinity recalculation" (48 ms), stage="Full map updating" (20 ms), stage="Detect lost partitions" (13 ms), stage="Exchange done" (41 ms), stage="Total time" (929 ms)]
[sys-#56%ignite-192.168.111.56-8082%] INFO org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture - Exchange longest local stages [startVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2, minorTopVer=0], resVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2, minorTopVer=0], stage="Affinity fetch" (364 ms) (parent=Determine exchange type), stage="Restore partition states [grp=gatewayNodeAndMqttTopicCache]" (24 ms) (parent=Restore partition states), stage="Restore partition states [grp=GateWay-192.168.111.65-53400]" (24 ms) (parent=Restore partition states), stage="Restore partition states [grp=thingInfoCache]" (23 ms) (parent=Restore partition states), stage="Affinity initialization (local join) [grp=thingInfoCache]" (48 ms) (parent=Affinity recalculation), stage="Affinity initialization (local join) [grp=nodeInfoCache]" (48 ms) (parent=Affinity recalculation), stage="Affinity initialization (local join) [grp=gatewayNodeAndMqttTopicCache]" (48 ms) (parent=Affinity recalculation)]
[exchange-worker-#45%ignite-192.168.111.56-8082%] INFO org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager - Skipping rebalancing (nothing scheduled) [top=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2, minorTopVer=0], force=false, evt=NODE_JOINED, node=a59

reblance worked in version 2.6 and 2.7：
[sys-#53%ignite-192.168.111.56-8082%] INFO org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor - Finish proxy initialization, cacheName=ignite-sys-cache, localNodeId=662140b5-f5f5-4ec8-8cba-375232bd89ae
[sys-#53%ignite-192.168.111.56-8082%] INFO org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor - Finish proxy initialization, cacheName=routeInfoAndComputeCache, localNodeId=662140b5-f5f5-4ec8-8cba-375232bd89ae
[sys-#53%ignite-192.168.111.56-8082%] INFO org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor - Finish proxy initialization, cacheName=thingInfoCache, localNodeId=662140b5-f5f5-4ec8-8cba-375232bd89ae
[sys-#53%ignite-192.168.111.56-8082%] INFO org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor - Finish proxy initialization, cacheName=Compute-192.168.111.65-53400, localNodeId=662140b5-f5f5-4ec8-8cba-375232bd89ae
[sys-#53%ignite-192.168.111.56-8082%] INFO org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor - Finish proxy initialization, cacheName=nodeInfoCache, localNodeId=662140b5-f5f5-4ec8-8cba-375232bd89ae
[sys-#53%ignite-192.168.111.56-8082%] INFO org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture - Completed partition exchange [localNode=662140b5-f5f5-4ec8-8cba-375232bd89ae, exchange=GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2, minorTopVer=0], evt=NODE_JOINED, evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=662140b5-f5f5-4ec8-8cba-375232bd89ae, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.111.56], sockAddrs=[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500, /192.168.111.56:47500], discPort=47500, order=2, intOrder=2, lastExchangeTime=1594192501312, loc=true, ver=2.7.6#20190912-sha1:21f7ca41, isClient=false], done=true], topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2, minorTopVer=0], durationFromInit=2318]
[exchange-worker-#43%ignite-192.168.111.56-8082%] INFO org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager - Rebalancing scheduled [order=[nodeInfoCache, thingInfoCache, routeInfoAndComputeCache, gatewayNodeAndMqttTopicCache], top=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2, minorTopVer=0], force=false, evt=NODE_JOINED, node=662140b5-f5f5-4ec8-8cba-375232bd89ae]
[exchange-worker-#43%ignite-192.168.111.56-8082%] INFO org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionDemander - Prepared rebalancing [grp=nodeInfoCache, mode=SYNC, supplier=c6c121bc-dd87-453d-b524-0cf5b6b13fe1, partitionsCount=512, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2, minorTopVer=0], parallelism=1]
[sys-#54%ignite-192.168.111.56-8082%] INFO org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionDemander - Started rebalance routine [nodeInfoCache, supplier=c6c121bc-dd87-453d-b524-0cf5b6b13fe1, topic=0, fullPartitions=[0-511], histPartitions=[]]
[sys-#55%ignite-192.168.111.56-8082%] INFO org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionDemander - Completed (final) rebalancing [grp=nodeInfoCache, supplier=c6c121bc-dd87-453d-b524-0cf5b6b13fe1, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2, minorTopVer=0], progress=1/1, time=101 ms]
[sys-#55%ignite-192.168.111.56-8082%] INFO org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionDemander - Completed rebalance future: RebalanceFuture [grp=CacheGroupContext [grp=nodeInfoCache], topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2, minorTopVer=0], rebalanceId=1, routines=1]
[sys-#55%ignite-192.168.111.56-8082%] INFO org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionDemander - Prepared rebalancing [grp=thingInfoCache, mode=SYNC, supplier=c6c121bc-dd87-453d-b524-0cf5b6b13fe1, partitionsCount=512, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2, minorTopVer=0], parallelism=1]
[sys-#56%ignite-192.168.111.56-8082%] INFO org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionDemander - Started rebalance routine [thingInfoCache, supplier=c6c121bc-dd87-453d-b524-0cf5b6b13fe1, topic=0, fullPartitions=[0-511], histPartitions=[]]
[sys-#57%ignite-192.168.111.56-8082%] INFO org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionDemander - Completed (final) rebalancing [grp=thingInfoCache, supplier=c6c121bc-dd87-453d-b524-0cf5b6b13fe1, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2, minorTopVer=0], progress=1/1, time=21 ms]
[sys-#57%ignite-192.168.111.56-8082%] INFO org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionDemander - Completed rebalance future: RebalanceFuture [grp=CacheGroupContext [grp=thingInfoCache], topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2,minorTopVer=0], rebalanceId=1, routines=1]
[sys-#57%ignite-192.168.111.56-8082%] INFO org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionDemander - Prepared rebalancing [grp=routeInfoAndComputeCache, mode=SYNC, supplier=c6c121bc-dd87-453d-b524-0cf5b6b13fe1, partitionsCount=512,topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2, minorTopVer=0], parallelism=1]
[sys-#58%ignite-192.168.111.56-8082%] INFO org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionDemander - Started rebalance routine [routeInfoAndComputeCache, supplier=c6c121bc-dd87-453d-b524-0cf5b6b13fe1, topic=0, fullPartitions=[0-511], histPartitions=[]]
[sys-#59%ignite-192.168.111.56-8082%] INFO org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionDemander - Completed (final) rebalancing [grp=routeInfoAndComputeCache, supplier=c6c121bc-dd87-453d-b524-0cf5b6b13fe1, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2, minorTopVer=0], progress=1/1, time=26 ms]
[sys-#59%ignite-192.168.111.56-8082%] INFO org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionDemander - Completed rebalance future: RebalanceFuture [grp=CacheGroupContext [grp=routeInfoAndComputeCache], topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2, minorTopVer=0], rebalanceId=1, routines=1]
[sys-#59%ignite-192.168.111.56-8082%] INFO org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionDemander - Prepared rebalancing [grp=gatewayNodeAndMqttTopicCache, mode=SYNC, supplier=c6c121bc-dd87-453d-b524-0cf5b6b13fe1, partitionsCount=512, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2, minorTopVer=0], parallelism=1]
[sys-#46%ignite-192.168.111.56-8082%] INFO org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionDemander - Started rebalance routine [gatewayNodeAndMqttTopicCache, supplier=c6c121bc-dd87-453d-b524-0cf5b6b13fe1, topic=0, fullPartitions=[0-511], histPartitions=[]]
[sys-#53%ignite-192.168.111.56-8082%] INFO org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionDemander - Completed (final) rebalancing [grp=gatewayNodeAndMqttTopicCache, supplier=c6c121bc-dd87-453d-b524-0cf5b6b13fe1, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2, minorTopVer=0], progress=1/1, time=10 ms]
[sys-#53%ignite-192.168.111.56-8082%] INFO org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionDemander - Completed rebalance future: RebalanceFuture [grp=CacheGroupContext [grp=gatewayNodeAndMqttTopicCache], topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2, minorTopVer=0], rebalanceId=1, routines=1][main] INFO org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.deployment.GridDeploymentLocalStore - Class locally deployed: class org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration$IgniteAllNodesPredicate

Comment: Hi, can you add more details regarding the issue? Dou you see any exceptions?
Is it possible that you are struggling with baseline auto adjust - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61266725/how-to-disable-ignite-baseline-auto-just?

Comment: this don't have any exceptions! And only prompt rebrance skip ,but  i can't find value from cache in other node except first node with REPLICATED cache mode.

Comment: this is my CacheConfiguration :CacheConfiguration<String,ThingVo> cacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration<String,ThingVo>()
    .setDataRegionName("not-persistence-data-region").setCacheMode(CacheMode.REPLICATED)
    .setName("thingInfoCache").setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL)
    .setWriteSynchronizationMode(CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.FULL_SYNC);
  cacheConfiguration.setRebalanceMode(CacheRebalanceMode.SYNC);
  cacheConfiguration.setIndexedTypes(String.class, ThingVo.class);

Comment: Can you provide logs from nodes? One which works and one which does not.

Comment: Hi , I have added the log to the problem description！thanks!